# Dynamic td foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display a PHP array as table in which 8 `td`s in a `tr`, but I have no idea how to limit the `td` in inner loop.

```
 <?php
    $i=0;
    $related = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
    for($i=0;$i<count($related);$i++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($j=0;$j<8;$j++){
            echo "<td>".$related[$j]."</td>";
            $i++;   
        }
        echo $i;
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
?>
```

Comment: and where's the problem?

Comment: Yes we get what you want. But what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally i figure it out,

```
<?php
        $data = range(1, 20);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($data);)
        {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        for($j = 0; $i < count($data) && $j < 8; $i++, $j++) {
        echo "\t<td>$data[$i]</td>\n";
        }
        for(; $j < 8; $j++) {

        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // your array
    $related = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
    for($i=0;$i<count($related);$i++){
    $row = "";
    $row = "<tr>";
        for($j=0;$j<8;$j++){
        $row .= "<td>".$related[$j]."</td>";
    }
    $row .= "</tr>";
    echo $row;
}
?>
```

try this code